# Best practices for using FastCGI for highly loaded web server

Tags: fastcgi

I have a web server that sole task is to run images processing.
The image processing on   the web server loads the same XML settings file (up to 2MB).
To save XML file loading time for every request I use follow architecture:

1. The web server is Apache (2.2.16) with MPM prefork and FastCGI (fcgi_mod) with image processing application (C++).
2. Invoked image processing application loads the XML file and spawns N threads and each thread runs:

   thread_func()
   {
       FCGX_InitRequest
       while(true)
       {
           FCGX_Accept_r
           Request (image) processing and FCGX_FPrintF/FCGX_PutStr
           FCGX_Finish_r
       }
   }

One of the weakness of this model is that at most one thread in each Apache process will do its work while being between FCGX_Accept_r and FCGX_Finish_r calls. Does it worth then to have **1** thread **only** per process (single thread), but to increase the MaxClients ?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [fastcgi](http://www.fastcgi.com/mod_fastcgi/docs/mod_fastcgi.html) module, it's allow more than one thread per process

Comment: The number of threads is not the problem. I can create more than one thread per apache web server process. The question is if it worth it while the code execution is in between FCGX_Accept_r and FCGX_Finish_r calls.

Comment: each thread can take one request and handle this request, so yes

Comment: Does it mean that if I have 5 web server processes with 10 threads in each then 50 requests may be processed simultaneously?

Comment: depend of what is a "web server processes", it's a apache processes, or 1 process of your fcgi app, i think apache don't run one fcgi process by apache process, i have only use the worker mpm for few test, and i use nginx for testing in development

Comment: An one web server process invokes one process of my fcgi app. The fcgi app process has N (let's say 10) threads. The web server is configured to be MPM prefork, so the number of web server processes is equal to the number of the fcgi app processes.

Comment: so yes with 10 thread per process and 5 process you can handler 50 request simultaneously

Comment: It doesn't happens in my case. The number of simultaneously processed requests is as the number of web server processes. This is actually was the original question: how to make number of simultaneously processed requests as the number of threads.

Comment: it's a constraint of your apache module, see my first post, some module consider one factcgi process such a monothread process and limit the number of conccurent request at one, i never found the configure option for this, bu the fastcgi module don't have this problem

Comment: one other thing, you use the mpm_prefork mode, so one web process can  handle only one request at time, you should use the mpm_worker mode i think